# If $S = \{ (a_1, a_2): a_1, a_2 \in R \}$, then is $R$ necessarily the field over which the vector space $S$ is defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading through an introductory linear algebra textbook. My understanding is that a vector space, defined as a set, is defined over a given field.

If $S = \{ (a_1, a_2): a_1, a_2 \in R \}$, then is $R$ necessarily the field over which the vector space $S$ is defined? If not, why? Please give a counterexample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $S$ is just a set, unless you define the vector space operations and the scalar multiplication. There is an obvious definition for this set which will make it a two dimensional $S$ vector space, namely by defining addition as
$$((a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2)) \mapsto (a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2)$$
and scalar multiplication by
$$(\lambda,(a_1, a_2))\mapsto (\lambda a_1, \lambda a_2)$$
with $\lambda, a_i , b_i\in R$.

But if, e.g., $R=  \mathbb{R}$ you can make the set $S$ a one dimensional complex vector space if you define the operations appropriately. Addition would be the same, but multiplication would be defined as 
$$(z, (a_1, a_2) )\mapsto (z_1a_1-z_2a_2, z_1a_2 + z_2a_1)$$
for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$. (This is just the complex product of $z_1+iz_2$ with $a_1+ia_2$ written down component wise). With this definition of scalar multiplication the set $S$ is then a one dimensional complex vector space.

Comment: You can also go the other way and let $S = \Bbb C^2$, while it is really a four-dimensional real space.

Comment: @Arthur yes, there are several variations possible.

Comment: I'm a novice, so your response goes over my head. Can you please rephrase it for a beginner in linear algebra?

Comment: @ThePointer do you know the real and complex number systems and are you aware of the fact that these are fields?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: @I'll edit my answer

Comment: So although the elements of our vector space may be in a certain domain (say, real numbers), we can still define the field to be different (say, the complex numbers)? In which case, our operations with scalars would also be different?

Comment: And in addition to my comment above, wouldn't this invalidate the set as a vector space, since the operations would not satisfy the requirements for a vector space?

Comment: @ThePointer yes, sure.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you for your assistance.